# Sharing cx_Oracle cursor between threads or processes

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, psycopg2, cx-oracle

I have a database in Oracle. I need to export some data, process them and save the data into the file. In the table is oracle [sdo_geom](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28400/sdo_objgeom.htm#SPATL120) and I need convert the geometry into the [WKT format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text_representation_of_geometry). The geometry is really big, a big polygons with thousand of vertices. I am using [SDO_UTIL.TO_WKTGEOMETRY()](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SPATL/sdo_util-to_wktgeometry.htm#SPATL1251) function but it takes too long. Selecting (converting the geometry) into the database is a bottleneck in this case.

I think about **multihreading** or **multiprocessing** in Python. The scenario should looks something like this:

1. Create connection to the database
2. Create cx_Oracle.cursor
3. Then start multiple threads or processes sharing the cursor
4. In every thread (or process) I will select the data from the database (the same table) by chunks
5. Then the all the data will be send to the thread or process responsible for processing the data and saving to the file

I am selecting the data using `fetchmany()` via chunks:

```
def get_row_chunks(self):
    while True:
        rows = self.cursor.fetchmany()
        if not rows:
            break
        yield rows
```

So my question is, **is it possible to solve this problem using multithreading or multiprocessing and how** (using [cx_Oracle](https://oracle.github.io/python-cx_Oracle/)) or [psycopg2](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/) for PostgreSQL I think it doesn't matter. The cursor has the same behaviour in these libraries I think. Or is it not possible easily share cursor between threads or processes.

Possible solution will be pregenerate the WKT geometry in the database but this looks to me more general solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot perform more than one action on a cursor or connection in cx_Oracle simultaneously. So you can't do simultaneous fetches, for example. If you attempt to do so you will discover that the fetches block. As such, I would suggest that you simply perform the fetch in one thread and pass the data fetched off to another thread or threads for processing.

The other possibility is to create a pool which permits you to create multiple connections and use them in multiple threads (use the threaded=True parameter when you create the pool). You can then use each connection to query a different portion of the data.

Comment: Ok, but your suggestion doesn't help me because the problem is performace of SDO_UTIL.TO_WKTGEOMETRY function. Because of this function the fetching is too slow. I can fetch the data, then process them very fast and my threads for processing will wait again for fetching the other chunk of the data. Can be solution creating more connections and for example share only ROWNUM or something like that which tells new cursor in connection where should fetch the new chunk of the table? But I am not sure about performace of this because creating new connection is expensive.

Comment: You can use a pool to create multiple connections. Acquiring connections from a pool is very fast. And yes, you would have to do something like that if the database performance is the bottleneck.

Comment: Yeah, thanks a lot. I tried using threads for new connections with ThreadPoolExecutor today and I will try connection pool for better perfomance. You can change/amend your answer and I will accept the answer

Comment: Answer adjusted as requested.