# Share cursor object to multiple threads cx_oracle

Tags: python, cx-oracle

I am trying to fetch data from oracle table and write to csv using cx_oracle module of python.

It is working fine but when there is huge data it takes too much time. I want to optimize it using threading/multiprocessing.

Currently I am using a fixed cursor size let say 50k and executing fetchmany() method to get that much rows in one go.

I dont have a primary key with which I can order the table by creating multiple new connections to the database. So I am running this fetchmany () methods multiple times until no more data left to fetch.

I want to know how can I share that cursor to my threads so I can run fetchmany() in a parallel manner to complete the work 4-5x faster.

I tried to pass that cursor object as an argument but that is not working and giving me an error `DPI -1042 INVALID OCI NUMBER`

Comment: this may be a data issue,  try running your script without threading on the same data to see if you get the same error.

Comment: Not a data issue, i am able to get the data fine without threading. Infact, with threading loop is working once and rest loops give same error that means the cursor object being passed is not usable like that

Comment: according to this answer it is not possible to run multiple parallel fetches on the same cursor https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54945434/sharing-cx-oracle-cursor-between-threads-or-processes

Comment: Is there an alternative way to achieve parallel data read

Comment: if you have an indexed column with values that are evenly distributed in your data you can select distinct col from table then split the returned result between the threads so each thread would select from the table rows that match those values.   note that it must be indexed otherwise it will be very slow

Comment: You could open multiple connections and query different data ranges in each.

Comment: @chris that's not possible as I dont have any primary key to segregate data